# How to get the mean of a certain amount of value continuously?

Tags: python, serial-port, mean, pyserial

I'm receiving a large amount of data continuously from a serial port, and I would like to make a mean every time i receive for example 100 values, my question is what is the easiest way to do it ?

Here is my code :

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM23', 19200)

while 1 :

    var = ser.readline()
    fl = float(var)
    print(fl)
    KeyboardInterrupt

ser.close()
```

Comment: just add a counter and do the stuff every time when counter % 100 == 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off your original code, it might look something like this:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM23', 19200)
meanList = []
counter = 0
total = 0

while 1 :

    var = ser.readline()
    counter += 1
    fl = float(var)
    total += fl
    print(fl)

    if (counter >= 100):
        counter = 0
        meanList.append(total / 100.0)
        total = 0

    KeyboardInterrupt

ser.close()
return meanList
```

This will get you a list with all of the means in the program after every 100. You can change around numbers to adjust how often you want the mean taken.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution would be to use a fixed size queue that holds only the last N items. In your case, the last 100 items.

```
N = 100
values = collections.deque(maxlen=N)
```

When you need to calculate the moving average, you call a function such as:

```
def mean(items, size=N):
    return sum(items)/size
```

Plugging these ideas into your code, could be done this way:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM23', 19200)

while 1 :

    var = ser.readline()
    values.append(var)
    # This queue will keep the last 100 items. 
    # ...
    # ...
    # when you need to use the mean...
    print(mean(values))
    # ... the rest of your code
```

Just beware that until the queue is full, the average will not be right using the function as is. If you need the average for the first data, you need to modify the function slightly.